# How can I move /Library/Developer to an external disk?

Tags: xcode, development

Until Xcode 10 I was able to move the Xcode Library/Developer folder to an external drive using a symlink, in order to free up space on my main disk, like

```
ln -s /Volumes/*/Library/Developer /Users/*/Library/Developer
```

In Xcode 11, moving the Developer folder produces errors related to my .xib files, like

```
/Users/*project_directory*/objects/View.xib:1:1: Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7fbc697f2a20> System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater <IBSimulatorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7fbc68ecd0c0> deviceType=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8'. These intermediate objects were non-nil: ( …
```

[Restarting the CoreSimulatorService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832489/8520417), which is often proposed as the solution for this kind of errors, doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I know this is nearly a year old, but I'm having the same issue and wondering if you ever found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, might be a strech to call this an answer, but most of the stuff that requires hd space on a modern Xcode installation is located in your

```
$ ~/Library/Developer
```

directory (mostly simulator files), and within the Xcode app bundle itself, in my case Xcode alone needs 10 gigabyte plus around 6 gigabyte for the simulator files and only **1.3 gigabyte in /Library/Developer.**

I also do some Flutter development, so that is another 10 gigabyte for the Android sdk and 4 gigabyte for the emulator files, plus a couple for Flutter itself.

All those directories have been symlinked or aliased and works just fine on an external drive.
This is described in my answer regarding [moving Xcode and friends to an SSD drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59159232/2557056).

I also got some problems using [brew](https://brew.sh) when I moved the /Library/Developer stuff, so it's probably best to leave that wormhole alone and focus on moving the things that *does* take a lot of space.
If you've already messed it up, just install the command line package again using the xcode-select command as described in my other post and go through those steps that fits your setup.

I save around 50 gigabyte ++ on the system drive by using this method with Xcode, the simulator and all, and I don't have the problem you mentioned in your question. I've been doing this for a couple of years now. So it IS possible, even if I can't pinpoint why it's not working for you.

If you update the question, documenting:

- the file system in use on the external drive
- mount options you use for mounting it
- if you use FileVault or not on the system
- have you tried repairing the permissions on your whole user directory while booting into recovery mode? (In the terminal)

I'd have a bit more to work with probably.
But as of now I can't reproduce what you experience.

Also try using a good old "alias" for the developer directory, don't use the command line to make a symlink, just hold down the option and command keys while dragging the Developer directory back to where it used to be. Sometimes things work better with a symlink, but in other situations I've found aliases to be the only way...

Comment: Just a note that Xcode doesn't like an alias. Upon opening a project it immediately complains it's "Not a directory".

Comment: Here's my answers to your questions: 1) File system - APFS for internal and external, 2) Mount options - MacOS default settings, 2) FileVault - off, 4) Haven't had a chance to try that yet, will report back this evening.

Comment: Thank you @C.Sederqvist! symlink didn't work for me but alias did!